Using fixmap after early-init stage
I am currently applying hibernation to my linux kernel and I need to manually feed the system watchdog during the last stage of resuming hibernate_exit. However, during this assembly method, the ttbr1 is switched to a different map table, which means that the initial watchdog's virtual address cannot be used. I have read about the docs for fixmap and I believe that it might be the solution to my problem. I have mapped the physical address of the watchdog to a virtual address located in the permanent fix address area using __set_fixmap, and then passed it to hibernate_exit. However, the system crashes when I try to write something to this VA.
If I understand it correctly fixmap is only used during the system initialization stage and nowhere else. My question is: Can I use fixmap to map a PA during the initialization stage and then use this mapping anytime I need it? In other words, is this mapping always stored in the fixmap area unless I clear it? Also, is my assumption that the fixmap is not affected by the ttbr-switching correct?
I am working on ARM64.

@sawdust Sorry for not clarifying it in the post. I am working on arm64.

IIRC, fixmaps are gone as early as init stage in the kernel is done, you may not use them afterwards.

@0andriy Yes I second that. But I can initialize this mapping just before the place I need to use it. The thing is that I am not sure if this fixmap is affected by the ttbr-switching.
